# Virtual Directory IIS 8.5 disabling web.config check

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, asp.net, iis-8.5, virtualdirectories

I'm setting up a new template for our web server farm that will host the web application locally instead of from a UNC path.  There are a few folders in the application where data is written to that are required to be shared between all of the servers in the farm.

To do this without rewriting portions of the application I'm trying to create virtual directories in the web site configuration that point to a UNC path.  These virtual directories contain no code they are simply text files, images, etc that only need to run through the `StaticFileHandler`, however when I try to access any file in the VDIR I get a `500.19 exception` with saying it is unable to read/find the web.config that lives in that directory.  I don't have the VDIR setup as an application just a simple pointer with the authentication running as a domain user that has read access to the UNC path.

I've tried running the CASPol command to grant full trust to the UNC path as well as the aspnet_regiis -ga command for the domain user.

In IIS 6 you were able to open the properties of the VDIR and set the execute permissions to `Scripts only` without an application on the VDIR and that didn't require a `web.config` in the VDIR itself.  All of the documentation and videos I've reviewed on setting up VDIRs in IIS8.5 say there is no additional setup in creating a VDIR then setting the authentication if it requires something different then what the Application Pool and site is running as.

Configuration:

Server: Windows 2012R2 Standard

IIS: 8.5

ASP.Net: 4.0

Application Pool: Integrated Mode

Connect As: Domain User for both the App Pool, the WebSite and the VDIR

Is there a global setting that disable the requirement/check for a `web.config` file in the VDIR when it's not setup as an application?

Comment: I would say IIS tries to read the web.config file in the UNC path but fails even listing files in that directory. Can you try giving IIS_IUSRS read permissions.

Comment: I'll try. Does it still use that even when I se a custom account for authentication?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I found is that when I setup the authentication for the virtual directories I set them up with the domain user for the `Physical Path Credentials` I set the `Physical Path Credentials Logon Type` value to `Network` which was causing an `ACCESS DENIED` error.  When I set the type to any of the other options it loaded the content just fine.  I'm not exactly sure why `Network` option fails unless it has something to do with `Kerberos` returning an invalid token.

[Logon Types from MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms691229(v=vs.90).aspx)